# Showing there is a unique basis $\{p_1, p_2, p_3\}$ of $P_2(R)$ with certain properties

Tags: linear-algebra

> $P_2(R)$ is the set of polynomials of degree two or lower.
>
> Show that there is a unique basis $\{p_1, p_2, p_3\}$ of $P_2(R)$ with the property that $p_1(0) = 1, p_1(1) = p_1(2) = 0, p_2(1) = 1, p_2(0) = p_2(2) = 0$ and $p_3(2) = 1, p_3(0) = p_3(1) = 0$.

Stuck here. I know a proof might look something like "Suppose there were two different bases..." and then showing they must be the same, but I'm actually stuck on part of finding what one basis would be in the first place.

Comment: $P2(R)$ is the space of polynomial functions with degree $\leq$ 2?

Comment: yes it is, should have mentioned.

Comment: I'll try to get the answer for u later... but it isn't that trivial. It's a nice question

Comment: Yeah of all the problems on this problem set, it's what's stumped me. Thanks.

Comment: You'r welcome bro!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asked to prove two things:

- Existance: there is such a basis, and
- Uniqueness: there is at most one such basis.

The proof you describe is only for proving uniqueness. Uniqueness is almost always easier to prove than existance.

To prove such a basis exists, you need to show

1. That there are $3$ polynonomials $p_1, p_2, p_3$ in $P_2(\Bbb R)$ such that $$\begin{array} {ccc} p_1(0) = 1 & p_1(1) = 0 & p_1(2) = 0\\p_2(0) = 0 & p_2(1) = 1 & p_2(2) = 0\\p_3(0) = 0 & p_3(1) = 0 & p_3(2) = 1\end{array}$$
2. That $\{p_1, p_2, p_3\}$ is linearly independent
3. That the span of $\{p_1, p_2, p_3\}$ is all of $P_2(\Bbb R)$.

So start with this: if $p \in P_2(\Bbb R)$, then $p(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$ for some $a, b, c$. If $p(0) = r, p(1) = s, p(2) = t$, then we have the following linear system of equations in the three unknowns $a, b, c$:
$$p(0) = a\cdot 0 + b \cdot 0 + c = r\\p(1) = a\cdot 1 + b \cdot 1 + c = s\\p(2) = a\cdot 4 + b \cdot 2 + c = t$$
This system is non-degenerate and so has a unique solution for any given $r, s, t$, which you should be able to easily produce.

This gives you directly the existence of the three polynomials $p_1, p_2, p_3$. It also shows that every polynomial in $P_2(\Bbb R)$ is in their span, for if $q \in P_2(\Bbb R)$, then $q$ is the unique polynomial $p$ above when $r = q(0), s = q(1), t = q(2)$. But note that $q(0)p_1 + q(1)p_2 + q(2)p_3$ is also a polynomial in $P_2(\Bbb R)$ with the same values at $x = 0,1,2$. Hence it must be $q$.

That $p_1, p_2, p_3$ are linearly independent is obvious, as any linear combination of $p_2$ and $p_3$ must be $0$ at $x = 0$ and so cannot be $p_1$. Similarly $x = 2$ and $x = 3$ show that $p_2$ and $p_3$ cannot be written as linear combinations of the other two either.

Lastly, if $q_1, q_2, q_3$ where another such basis, then note that the polynomials $q_1 - p_1, q_2 - p_2, q_3 - p_3$ each have the property that their values at $0, 1,$ and $2$ are all $0$. Apply the result above again to see that each of these polynomials must be uniformly 0, which proves the uniqueness.

Answer (score 0):

Paul Sinclair's solution is fine, but if you want to find $p_1,p_2,p_3$, you can do it this way:

First, you know that if $p(x)$ is a polynomial and $p(a)=0$ then $x-a$ is a factor. So $p_1$ must be $m_1(x-1)(x-2)$ for some constant $m_1$, and you can evaluate that constant by considering $p_1(0)$. Similarly, $p_2=m_2x(x-2)$, and $p_3=m_3x(x-1)$, for some easily evaluated constants $m_2$ and $m_3$.